# Game port to unity: Web posting

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am porting a game from Java Native to Unity. While the game is working correctly, I am having trouble posting the score using the same web services.

Java Code:

```
public static   String gameConfigURL = "http://192.168.0.140/services/scoreupload.svc/json/GetGameConfigurationLite";
public static   String scoreUploadURL = "http://192.168.0.140/services/scoreupload.svc/json/Upload";
public static final  String MagicKey = "0GmWDa6j"; 
private static  int timeoutConnection = 60000; 

 public static enum RequestSource
    { 
       Unknown,
        System, 
        Person; 
    } 

public static Response sendRequestForResult(Request request, String Url,
        Activity activity, Response response) throws JSONException,
        ClientProtocolException, IOException,ConnectTimeoutException {

    /** Code to create a JSON request from requestObject **/ 
    JSONObject object = request.getJSON();
    JSONObject requestObject = new JSONObject();
    requestObject.put("request", object);

    Log.v("","REQUEST:"+requestObject.toString());
    /** Add code to create a HttpPostRequest **/
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(Url);

    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
    HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
    String jsonValueString = null;
    StringEntity se = null;
    try {
        se = new StringEntity(requestObject.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    httpPost.setEntity(se);
    httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/json"); 
    /**
     * add code to attach the JSON object received from request to the
     * HttpPostRequest Add Code to execute HttpRequest
     **/
    httpResponse = client.execute(httpPost);

    /** Get string from the HttpRespnse **/
    jsonValueString = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());

    Log.v("","RESPONSE:"+jsonValueString);

    /** Create JSON object from incoming String **/
    JSONObject repliedObject = new JSONObject(jsonValueString);

    response.fromJSON(repliedObject);  
    return response;
```

How Do I convert this to unity C#.

So far I have this:

```
JSONObject j = new JSONObject ();

    j.AddField ("Id", "1234567890");
    j.AddField ("MagicKey", ApplicationServices.magicKey); 
    j.AddField ("RequestedBy", "09996f84-1a06-e211-a518-001aa020d699");
    j.AddField ("Timestamp", "/Date(1547535370953)/"); 
    j.AddField ("RequestSource", "Person");
    j.AddField ("RequestedGameId", "375b43c0-91be-e011-a505-001aa020d699"); 
    j.AddField ("RequestedPersonId", "09996f84-1a06-e211-a518-001aa020d699");
    string json = j.ToString ();

    Dictionary<string, string> header = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    header.Add ("Accept", "application/json");
    header.Add ("Content-Type", "text/json");

    byte[] encode = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes (json.ToCharArray ());


    WWW getConfig = new WWW (ApplicationServices.gameConfigURL, encode, header);

    yield return getConfig;

    if (getConfig.error != null) {
        Debug.Log (getConfig.error);
    } else {
        Debug.Log (getConfig.text);
    }
```

This does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

For "POST" you should use WWWForm instead of WWW.
Take a look [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/11021/how-can-i-send-and-receive-data-to-and-from-a-url.html)